# GPG warnings and failed to fetch errors while trying to update with APT

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa, update-manager

I am a new Ubuntu user. I tried to update my Ubuntu and it showed these errors.

```
Reading package list... Done
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg:
    Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease:  
    Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease:  
    Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease:  
    Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg:
    Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/next/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: 
    The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
    NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/next/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead
```

How can these be fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I noted some of the error messages refer to precise which is Ubuntu 12.04.  Are you updating from 12.04 to 16.04?  Not only you need to copy the text as @EliahKagan suggests but you need a better description of what you were trying to do when you got the error messages (like updating from 12.04 to 16.04 if that is the case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Answer (score 2):

Just checked that PPA that's complaining about the "Failed to fetch" error.

From the [dist directory of that PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/next/ubuntu/dists/), it does not have a version for Xenial. So the only solution might be remove that ppa.

If you're upgrading from 12.04 to 16.04, you can try to remove that ppa with:
`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:tualatrix/next`

And update the software list with `sudo apt-get update`, then you should be able to continue your upgrade task.

Or you can try to upgrade to 14.04, that ppa is available for Trusty.

Answer (score 0):

- execute the below commands one by one..
- **rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/***
- If use using proxy, export the proxy settings by the below commands
  in terminal with root privilege:
- **export http_proxy=http://proxyaddress:port**
- run the add ppa with sudo environment setting by
- **sudo -E add-apt-repository**